# Why use underscores?

Tags: objective-c

The following example illustrates how you might implement a dealloc method for a Person class:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (retain) NSString *firstName;
@property (retain) NSString *lastName;
@property (assign, readonly) NSString *fullName;
@end

@implementation Person
// ...
- (void)dealloc
    [_firstName release];
    [_lastName  release];
    [super      dealloc];
}
@end
```

The above is from Apple documentation : 
[memory management example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

My question is why there are underscores before firstName and lastName in dealloc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `self.firstName` you're actually calling the getter `firstName` (same for `self.firstName = @""` calling `setFirstName:`. Those getter and setter methods actually access the underlying instance variable, like this:

```
- (NSString *)firstName
{
    return _firstName;
}
```

When you do _firstName, you're directly accessing the instance variable without going through the setter. The reason that people directly access the instance variable during `init` and `dealloc` is that the setter method or an object which is observing[1] the property could then run code. This could be bad, because the object probably hasn't either finished initializing itself (in `init`), or some of it's properties have been released (in `dealloc`).

When you write `@sythesize firstName = _firstName`, you are specifically naming the underlying instance variable `_firstName` rather than `firstName`. This way, you don't accidentally type `firstName` and bypass the setter method & KVO. If you don't write an `@synthesize`, the compiler automatically names the instance variable `_firstName`.

Just a personal recommendation -- I would use ARC so that you don't have to deal with dealloc.

[1] Key-Value observing is a way in which an object can register to be notified of changes to a property. It is automatically provided through `@synthesize` or correctly named `getter` and `setter` methods.

Answer (score 2):

The properties would typically be synthesized thus:

```
@synthesize firstName = _firstName, …;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the synthesize statement added manually and what is the benefit of adding the "  = _firstName, ..." ?

Comment: I think it may only apply to ARC.  If ARC were not used then the example would be written differently.

Comment: @Stanley: It's a convention that disambiguates the property from the ivar. It isn't strictly necessary, but it clarifies intent.

Answer (score 1):

Approach :: By default when you synthesize the getter and setter accessor methods it is assumed that the property and ivar have the same name.

This can make it confusing at first glance as to when you are using the getter/setter methods and when you are accessing the ivar directly.

The alternative is name the ivar differently from the property. A common approach is to use an underscore to prefix the ivars names.

You can Refer this link : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/02/08/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link.  Guess I have to go over the difference between ivar and the property name.

Comment: Your answer is very good, but Max also mentioned KVO as a reason for giving an underscore for ivar.  Unfortunately only one answer can be accepted, up voted your answer instead.  Thanks for your kind assistance...